# WebRTC is not streaming video to other client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, webrtc

i'm new here and i started learning java script like 2 weeks ago.
i'm trying to build a video conference private website and the problem is :
video stream is showing on user A and User B but they cant see each others' stream
here is the javascript app code

```js
var AppProcess = (function(){
    var peers_connection_ids = [];
    var peers_connection = [];
    var remote_vid_stream = [];
    var remote_aud_stream = [];
    var videoCamTrack;
    var local_div;
    var serverProcess;
    var audio;
    var isAudioMute = true;
    var rtp_aud_senders = [];
    var video_state = {
        None:0,
        Camera: 1,
        ScreenShare:2,
    };
    var video_st =  video_state.None;
    var rtp_vid_senders = [];
    

    async function _init(SDP_function, my_connid){
    serverProcess = SDP_function;
    my_connection_id = my_connid;
    eventProcess();
    local_div = document.getElementById("locaVideoPlayer");
    }
    
    function eventProcess(){
        $("#micMuteUnmute").on("click", async function(){
            if(!audio){
                await loadAudio();
            }
            if(!audio){
                alert("Audio Permission Is Not Granted");
                return;
            }
            if(isAudioMute){
                audio.enabled = true;
                $(this).html("<span class='material-icons'>mic</span>");
                updateMediaSenders(audio, rtp_aud_senders);
            }else{
                audio.enabled = false;
                $(this).html("<span class='material-icons'>mic_off</span>");
                removeMediaSenders(rtp_aud_senders);
            }
            isAudioMute = !isAudioMute;


        });

        $("#videoCamOnOff").on("click", async function(){
            if(video_st == video_state.Camera){
              await videoProcess(video_state.None);
            }else{
                await videoProcess(video_state.Camera);
            }
        });

        $("#btnScreenShareOnOff").on("click", async function(){
            if(video_st == video_state.ScreenShare){
              await videoProcess(video_state.None);
            }else{
                await videoProcess(video_state.ScreenShare);
            }
        });

    }
    


    async function videoProcess(newVideoState){
    if(newVideoState == video_state.None){
        $("videoCamOnOff").html("<span class='material-icons'>videocam_off</span>");
    }
    if(newVideoState == video_state.Camera){
        $("videoCamOnOff").html("<span class='material-icons'>videocam_on</span>");
    }
    try{
      var vstream = null;
      if(newVideoState == video_state.Camera){
          vstream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
              video:{
                  width:1920,
                  height:1080,
              },
              audio:false,
          });
      }else if(newVideoState == video_state.ScreenShare){
        vstream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
            video:{
                width:1920,
                height:1080,
            },
            audio:false,
        });
      }
      if(vstream && vstream.getVideoTracks().length > 0){
          videoCamTrack = vstream.getVideoTracks()[0];
          if(videoCamTrack){
              local_div.srcObject = new MediaStream([videoCamTrack]);
              await updateMediaSenders(videoCamTrack, rtp_vid_senders); 
              
              
          }
      }

  } catch(e){
      console.log(e);
      return;
    }
  video_st = newVideoState;
  
  

    }

    var iceConfiguration = {
        iceServers:[
            {
                urls:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
            },
            {
                urls:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
            },
        ],
    };

    async function setConnection(connid){
        var connection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);

        connection.onnegotiationneeded = async function(event) {
            await setOffer(connid);
        };
        connection.onicecandidate = function(event) {
            if(event.candidate){
                serverProcess(JSON.stringify({icecandidate: event.candidate}),
                connid);
            }
        };
        connection.ontrack = function(event){
         if(!remote_vid_stream[connid]){
            remote_vid_stream[connid] = new MediaStream();
         }
         if(!remote_aud_stream[connid]){
            remote_aud_stream[connid] = new MediaStream();
         }

         if(event.track.kind == "video"){
            remote_vid_stream[connid]
            .getVideoTracks()
            .forEach((t)=>remote_vid_stream[connid].removeTrack(t));
            remote_vid_stream[connid].addTrack(event.track);
            var remoteVideoPlayer = document.getElementById("v_" + connid);
            remoteVideoPlayer.srcObject = null;
            remoteVideoPlayer.srcObject = remote_vid_stream[connid];
            remoteVideoPlayer.load();

         } else if(event.track.kind == "audio"){
            remote_aud_stream[connid]
            .getAudioTracks()
            .forEach((t)=>remote_aud_stream[connid].removeTrack(t));
            remote_aud_stream[connid].addTrack(event.track);
            var remoteAudioPlayer = document.getElementById("a_" + connid);
            remoteAudioPlayer.srcObject = null;
            remoteAudioPlayer.srcObject = remote_aud_stream[connid];
            remoteAudioPlayer.load();

         }

        };

        peers_connection_ids[connid] = connid;
        peers_connection[connid] = connection;

        if(video_st == video_state.Camera || 
            video_st == video_state.ScreenShare
            ){
            if(videoCamTrack){
                updateMediaSenders(videoCamTrack, rtp_vid_senders); 
            }
            
        }
        return connection;
    }
    
    function connection_status(connection){
        
        if((connection && connection.connectionState == "new" || 
        connection.connectionState == "connecting" || 
        connection.connectionState == "connected")){
            
            return true;
            
        }else {
            
            return false;
        }
    }
    async function updateMediaSenders(track, rtp_senders){
        for(var con_id in peers_connection_ids){
            if(connection_status(peers_connection[con_id])){
            if(rtp_senders[con_id] && rtp_senders[con_id].track){
                rtp_senders[con_id].replaceTrack(track);
               
            }else {
                rtp_senders[con_id] = peers_connection[con_id].addTrack(track);
               
            }
    
            }
        }
    }


    async function setOffer(connid){
    var connection = peers_connection[connid];
    var offer = await connection.createOffer();
    await connection.setLocalDescription(offer);

    serverProcess(JSON.stringify({
        offer : connection.LocalDescription,
    }), connid);
    }

    async function SDPProcess(message, from_connid){
        message = JSON.parse(message);
        if(message.answer){
          await peers_connection[from_connid]
          .setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.answer));
          

        }else if(message.offer){
         if(!peers_connection[from_connid]){
             await setConnection(from_connid); 
             }
             await peers_connection[from_connid]
             .setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.offer));

            var answer = await peers_connection[from_connid].createAnswer();

            await peers_connection[from_connid].setLocalDescription(answer);
            serverProcess(JSON.stringify({
                answer : answer,
            }), from_connid);
         
        }else if (message.icecandidate){
            if(!peers_connection[from_connid]){
                await setConnection(from_connid);
            }
            try{
                await peers_connection[from_connid].addIceCandidate(message.
                    icecandidate);
                
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    }



    return {
        setNewConnection: async function(connid){
            await setConnection(connid);
        },
        init : async function(SDP_function, my_connid){
           await _init(SDP_function, my_connid);
        },
        processClientFunc : async function(data, from_connid){ 
            await SDPProcess(data, from_connid);
        },
    };
})();
var MyApp = (function(){
    var socket = null;
    var user_id = "";
    var meeting_id = "";

      function init(uid, mid){
          user_id = uid;
          meeting_id = mid;
          $("#meetingContainer").show();
          $("#me h2").text(user_id + "(ME");
          document.title = user_id;

       event_process_for_signaling_server();
      }
      
      function event_process_for_signaling_server(){
          socket = io.connect();
             
          var SDP_function = function(data, to_connid){
              socket.emit("SDPProcess", {
              message: data,
              to_connid: to_connid,
              });
          }
          socket.on("connect", () =>{
              if(socket.connected){
                  AppProcess.init(SDP_function, socket.id);
                  if(user_id != "" && meeting_id != ""){
                      socket.emit("userconnect", {
                          displayName: user_id,
                          meetingid: meeting_id,
                      });
                  }
              }
          });

        socket.on("inform_others_about_me", function(data){
            addUser(data.other_user_id, data.connId);
            AppProcess.setNewConnection(data.connId);
           
        });
        socket.on("inform_me_about_other_user", function(other_users){
            if(other_users){
                for(var i = 0; i<other_users.length; i++){
                    addUser(other_users[i].user_id,
                        other_users[i].connectionId);
                        AppProcess.setNewConnection(other_users[i].connectionId);
                        
                }
            }
            
            
        });

        socket.on("SDPProcess", async function(data){
            await AppProcess.processClientFunc(data.message, data.from_connid);
        });
      }
      function addUser(other_user_id, connId){
      var newDivId = $("#otherTamplate").clone();
      newDivId = newDivId.attr("id", connId).addClass("other");
      newDivId.find("h2").text(other_user_id);
      newDivId.find("video").attr("id", "v_id"+connId);
      newDivId.find("audio").attr("id", "a_"+connId);
      newDivId.show();
      $("#divUsers").append(newDivId);


      }
    return{
        _init: function(uid, mid){
            init(uid, mid);
        },
    };
})();
```

here is also the server.js file

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("Listening On Port 3000");
});

const io = require("socket.io")(server,{
    allowEIO3: true,
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"")));

var userConnections = [];
io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
    console.log("socket id is", socket.id);
    socket.on("userconnect", (data)=>{
        console.log("userconnect", data.displayName, data.meetingid);

        var other_users = userConnections.filter(
            (p) => p.meeting_id == data.meetingid);
        userConnections.push({
            connectionId: socket.id,
            user_id: data.displayName,
            meeting_id: data.meetingid,
        });
      
        other_users.forEach((v) =>{
            socket.to(v.connectionId).emit("inform_others_about_me", {
            other_user_id: data.displayName,
            connId: socket.id,
            
            })
        });
        socket.emit("inform_me_about_other_user", other_users);
        

    });
    socket.on("SDPProcess", (data)=>{
        socket.to(data.to_connid).emit("SDPProcess",{
            message: data.message,
            from_connid: socket.id,
        })
    })
});
```

Example index html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Kira Meet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="kira_public/k_assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="kira_public/k_assets/css/k_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="kira_public/k_assets/css/index_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="kira_public/k_assets/js/k_meet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            /*const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            var meeting_id = urlParams.get('meetingID');*/
            meeting_id = window.prompt('EnterRoomID (8-d number)')
            user_id = window.prompt('Enter Your User ID');

            if(!user_id || !meeting_id){
                alert('User ID Or Meeting ID Is Missing');
                window.location.href = '/kira_action.html';
                return;
            }
            $("#meetingContainer").show();

            MyApp._init(user_id, meeting_id);
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="d-flex flex-column home-wrap">
        <div class="g-top text-light">
            <div class="top-remote-video-show-wrap d-flex">
                <div id="meetingContainer" class="w-75" style="display:none;">
                <div class="call-wrap" style="background-color: black;">
                <div class="video-wrap" id="divUsers" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap">
                    <div id="me" class="userbox display-center flex-column">
                        <h2 class="display-center" style="font-size: 14px;"></h2>
                        <div class="display-center">
                            <video autoplay muted id="locaVideoPlayer"></video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="otherTamplate" class="userbox display-center flex-column" style="display:none">
                    <h2 class="display-center" style="font-size: 14px;"></h2>
                    <div class="display-center">
                          <video autoplay muted></video>
                          <audio autoplay controls muted style="display:none"></audio>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="g-top-left bg-light text-secondary w-25 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between ps-2 pe-2">
                <div class="top-left-participant-wrap pt-2 cursor-pointer">
                    <div class="top-left-participant-icon">
                        <span class="material-icons">people</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="top-left-participant-count">2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="top-left-chat-wrap pt-2 cursor-pointer">
                    <span class="material-icons">message</span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="top-left-time-wrap"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="g-bottom bg-light m-0 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
           <div class="bottom-left d-flex" style="height: 10vh;">
        <div class="display-center cursor-pointer meeting-details-button">
            Meeting Details<span class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</span>
        </div>
        </div>
           <div class="bottom-middle d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 10vh;">
               <div class="mic-toggle-wrap action-icon-style display-center me-2 cursor-pointer" id="micMuteUnmute">
                   <span class="material-icons">mic_off</span>
               </div>
               <div class="end-call-wrap action-icon-style display-center me-2 cursor-pointer">
                   <span class="material-icons text-danger">call</span>
               </div>
               <div class="video-toggle-wrap action-icon-style display-center cursor-pointer" id="videoCamOnOff">
                   <span class="material-icons">videocam_off</span></div>
           </div>
           <div class="bottom-right d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center me-3" style="height: 10vh;">
               <div class="present-now-wrap d-flex justify-content-center flex-column align-items-center me-5 cursor-pointer" id="btnScreenShareOnOff">
                    <span class="material-icons">present_to_all</span>
                 <div>Present Now</div>
                </div>
                 
               <div class="option-wrap cursor-pointer d-flex display-center" style="height: 10vh; position: relative;">
            <div class="option-icon">
                <span class="material-icons">more_vert</span>
            </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

i don't know exactly where did i mess it up but i'm sure i did.

Comment: Are User A and B on the same computer? If not, In order to get the local media stream, your website should an SSL certificate, otherwise, it does not work, you may use try-catch to catch exceptions to see what is going on.

Comment: @TheKNVB yes bro they are on the same computer, webrtc:about is showing the rtc connection estableshed and running, video is displaying on both clients but you only see yourself on both sides, client can't see other client's stream